# SQL - Two columns split by grouped data into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been tasked with coming up with a means of translating the following data:

```
Column_A    Column_B
----------------------
    A           AA
    A           BB
    B           CC
    B           DD
    C           EE
    C           FF
    C           GG
```

to

```
A   B   C
----------
AA  CC  EE
BB  DD  FF
        GG
```

and soon..

The Column_B can be NULLs or blanks, either is fine, and the Column_A would need to be dynamic. I've tried to research and have landed on PIVOT but its required 3 columns to convert. I've tried [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132484) answer but the result is

```
A   B   C
----------
AA  BB  CC
DD  EE  FF
GG
```

Column_A can have min of 25 Unique records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff said `row_number()` to generate the line number and then aggregation and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42489547/2928136) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132484) answer, i just added a temp column as `row_number()` as pivot.

```
DECLARE @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_A)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A FROM t) AS A

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
= ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
+ 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMNA) + ', '') AS '
+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_A)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A FROM t) AS A

WITH PivotData
AS (
    SELECT COLUMN_A --The row group
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY COLUMN_A ORDER BY COLUMN_A ASC
                ) AS TheRow --The value that will form columns
        ,COLUMN_B
    FROM 
        t
    )
SELECT '+@PivotSelectColumnNames+'
FROM PivotData
PIVOT(max(COLUMN_B) FOR COLUMN_A IN (
            '+@PivotColumnNames+'
            )) AS P
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to generate the line number and then aggregation:

```
select max(case when a = 'A' then b end) as a,
       max(case when a = 'B' then b end) as b,
       max(case when a = 'C' then b end) as c
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: max(case when a = 'A' then b end) this will be around 25 different conditions and need to be dynamic

Comment: @chiru . . . If you need 25 columns, you need 25 columns and need to list them each separately.

Comment: i've achieved the result bro and updated the answer.